# Sparql: how to GROUP BY More Than One Column

Tags: group-by, sparql

In SPARQL, we can group the rows by a column through the gollowing syntax:

```
GROUP BY ?colName
```

Can we group by more than 1 columns eg:

```
GROUP BY (?colName1 + ?colName2 + ?colName3)
```

Suppose a query like:

```
Select ?a ?b ?c (MIN(?y) AS ?d)
Where {
....
}
GROUP BY (?a + ?b + ?c)
```

But this query does not work.

Answer (score 9):

You can `GROUP BY` multiple variables (not columns) by listing them with a space in between:

```
GROUP BY ?a ?b ?c
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Ben Companjen's answer of

```
GROUP BY ?a ?b ?c
```

you need to fix the SELECT line as you can't pass out the indeterminate non-group keys without explicitly saying so e.g.

```
SELECT (sample(?a) as ?A) (sample(?b) as ?B) (sample(?c) as ?C) (min(?y) as ?d)
```

Comment: I hadn't read about `SAMPLE` yet, but now that I did, I think the `SELECT` clause does not need to be fixed. `SAMPLE` is needed for variables in the `SELECT` clause that are _not_ in the `GROUP BY` clause and not aggregated otherwise, but `?a ?b ?c` are exactly the variables in the `GROUP BY` clause. If some additional variable `?e` were `SELECT`ed, but not `GROUP BY`ed, it would need to be `SAMPLE`d.

Comment: The variables in `SELECT` and in `GROUP BY` just need to be in the same exact order, `SELECT` then as one or few more variables, to show the sums, etc.

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried something like

SELECT  ?a+b+?c, (MIN(?y) AS ?d)
Where {
....
}
GROUP BY (?a+?b+?c)

This works in SQL Server just fine